# There are no use of timeout for search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I set the search timeout by 1s,but there is no use.

url:`http://xxx:9200/flume-*/detail/_search?timeout=1s`

resp:`"took": 40356,
    "timed_out": true,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 495,
        "successful": 495,
        "failed": 0
    },`

Is there any setting to make the `timeout` useful?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `timeout` unit is being defined as milliseconds. So what if you have the uri as such:

```
http://xxx:9200/flume-*/detail/_search?timeout=1000
```

But I suggest you to go through [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3627) ticket which actually points out the issues on returning a response after the timeout has elapsed. Hope it helps!